# Why does RequireJS optimizer omit '/' in module-names in Windows?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, minify, optimization

After running our RequireJS build scripts on Windows for a module that lives in components/Cinema.Helper.Ticket.js, it outputs the following module name

```
define("componentsCinema.Helper.Ticket" ...
```

However, on my Mac computer it works just fine, slash included. What could be the reason for that? What can we do to prevent it from happening?